# how does the database act when a page is online?

Tags: php, database, web

i build a site for my school project where u can add an appointment to a doctor in it.
In the website there is a page where u see all the available times for a specific day and you can choose one.
But how does that work when a site like this is on the web and several people can enter it at once? If person A' changed the database (added a appointment) will person B' that is already in the site see the change? or will he need to reload the page to see the change?
i tried looking online but didnt find any answer.
thanks for the help

Comment: You could do something like Ticketmaster. Once the user clicks on a date, you "lock" it for a few minutes. It's kind of like a reservation system, but only lasts for a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question **NO** unless you are using **AJAX** or some kind of `push notifications` like `pusher` for PHP.

if `Person A` adds record, `Person B` wont be able to see the change until page is refreshed.

To achieve above you will need **AJAX** and the easiest way in my opinion is to use `JQuery AJAX` which will refresh every few seconds.

So would be something like this:

```
//refresh every 5 seconds
setInterval(function() {
      $.ajax({
         type: 'get',
         url: 'PATH_TO_YOUR_PHP_SCRIPT',
         data: {key1: value1, key2: value2}, //$_GET parameters to pass
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(result) {
           $.each(result, function(i, item) {
               //do what you need to do with returned data, append to table or so
           });
         }
      });
}, 5000);
```

Make sure to use `echo json_encode($data_array)` to return data on PHP side.